# How to run Android Virtual Device on React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, android-studio, react-native

I'm following https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html and I'm on the step to start the Android Virtual Device.

But once I do `android avd` I come the following where there is no Android Virtual Device for me to start with:

[image]

And when I do just `android` in the terminal I have:

[image]

What could I possibly be doing wrong? Thank you and will be sure to vote up and accept answer.

Comment: You need to install a system image. it will work fine then.

Comment: I advise installing Genymotion, you won't be opening Android Studio each time. Just run genymotion emulator, and in console, type react-native run-android. You can always see attached devices and launched emulators by typing adb devices